# SQL update query no such column in django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

When i try to call a method from my view which runs a raw SQL query i get an operational error however when i check the database using sqlite manager on firefox it shows i have this column with the correct value

//Wallet model

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='')
    amount = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_not_neg], default=0)

    def add_money(self, money):
        self.amount = self.amount + int(money)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('UPDATE wallet_wallet SET amount= %s WHERE username=%s' %(self.amount, self.username))

    def subtract_money(self, money):
        if int(money) > self.amount:
            raise ValidationError(
                ('%s greater than amount in wallet can not process.' % money),
                params={'value': money}
            )
        else:
            self.amount -= int(money)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('UPDATE wallet_wallet SET amount= %s WHERE username=%s' % (self.amount, self.username))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        permissions = (('add_money', 'can deposit money'), ('subtract_money', 'can take withdraw money'))
```

//add_money view

```
def add_money(request):
    print ("Request %s %s" % (request,type(request)))
    if request.user:
        if request.POST and request.POST.get('amount'):
            username = request.user.username
            add_amount = request.POST.get('amount')
            wallet = Wallet.objects.filter(username=username)
            wallet = wallet.get(pk=request.user.userprofile.wallet_id_id)
            print(wallet.username)
            wallet.add_money(add_amount)
            wallet.save()
            now = datetime.now()
            trans = Transaction(from_name=username, wallet_id=wallet.id, date=now, amount=add_amount)
            trans.save()
            print ("Request s %s" % request)
            return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'user': request.user})
        else:
            print ("Request  j %s" % request)
            return render(request, 'add_money.html')
    else:
        print ("Request rf %s" % request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?next={}'.format('/add_money/'))
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/ravinkohli/env_app_pw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/Users/ravinkohli/PycharmProjects/untitled1/wallet/views.py" in add_money
      22.             wallet.add_money(add_amount)
    File "/Users/ravinkohli/PycharmProjects/untitled1/wallet/models.py" in add_money
      24.         cursor.execute('UPDATE wallet_wallet SET amount= %s WHERE username=%s' %(self.amount, self.username))
    File "/Users/ravinkohli/env_app_pw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
    File "/Users/ravinkohli/env_app_pw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/Users/ravinkohli/env_app_pw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
      98.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
    File "/Users/ravinkohli/env_app_pw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      62.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
    File "/Users/ravinkohli/env_app_pw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
      316.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)

    Exception Type: OperationalError at /add_money/
    Exception Value: no such column: ravin
```

[image]

Comment: I've noticed you seem to be asking a lot of questions in quick succession, you should at least try to debug your own problems first before asking a question, once you've done that you'll be able to include what you've tried/researched into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fix to this particular problem

```
 cursor.execute('UPDATE wallet_wallet SET amount= %s WHERE username=%s'  ,  (self.amount, self.username))
```

Note how the % changes to , this uses parameter binding and also protects you to some extend from [SQL injection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/).

### The real solution.

Don't use raw sql here.

```
  def add_money(self, money):
        self.amount = self.amount + int(money)
        self.save()
```

Really, there isn't a need for it. just call save(). to make it even more compact you don't even need the add_money method at all!! Refer to the F expression approach I mentioned in your previous question.